# Set jQuery .css() based on variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the `margin-top` and `margin-left` values to half of an element's respective size so as to center it. However it just goes 50% on the left and top.

```
    var $img = document.getElementsByClassName('box'); 
    var $width = $img.clientWidth;
    var $height = $img.clientHeight;
    $('#overlay').append('<div id="boxOverlay"></div>');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('top', '50%');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('margin-top', '-$height/2');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('left', '50%');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('margin-left', '-$width/2');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('max-height','80%');
    $('#boxOverlay').css('max-width','90%');
    $('#boxOverlay').height($height);
    $('#boxOverlay').width($width);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $img = $('.box');
var $width = $img.width();
var $height = $img.height();
// ...
$('#boxOverlay').css('margin-top', (($height / 2) * -1));
$('#boxOverlay').css('margin-left', (($width / 2) * -1));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mghb/)

Also, it's a *best practice* to pass a style object to the css method:

```
var styles = {
    'margin-top': (($height / 2) * -1),
    'margin-left': (($width / 2) * -1)
};

$('#boxOverlay').css(styles);
```

With this approach, you only query the DOM once and you'll avoid multiple repaint and/or reflows (citation needed).

Comment: Err, isn't $img a collection of DOM elements? What are the values of $width and $height?

Comment: I'm making a slideshow based on certain specs. There are different image sizes and its meant to to pull the image height and width from the image.

Answer (score 1):

in jquery 
the margin-left is marginLeft
Remove the middle of the dash
you can try

```
$('#boxOverlay').css('marginTop', '-$height/2');
$('#boxOverlay').css('maxHeight','80%');
$('#boxOverlay').css('maxWidth','90%');
```

Comment: '-$height/2' is still a string and an invalid margin-top value.

Comment: $('#boxOverlay').css('marginTop', -$height/2);

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the single quote marks around the variables you want to use. By adding quote marks around your variables you're actually passing the function [.css()] a string literal instead of a variable.

[MDN - Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)